# What doneness is this steak?

Tags: steak

I just cooked a thin rib eye steak. I took its temperature 40 sec after removing it from the pan (all cooked outside) and it registered 135 degrees F. However, due to it being quite thin, it was hard to find the middle. I aimed for med-rare, but I think it may have been too rare. Here are some pictures.

Could anyone please indicate how done this stake was?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am particularly concerned this last piece was too rare.

Comment: looks medium-rare-ish. what is your concern ?

Comment: Concerned that it was too rare for safety reasons, as the cut was quite thin. What about the first two photos. Thank you

Comment: that was my comment for the 1st photo

Comment: @Max I see. so what about the last two?

Comment: Steak can be rare and still safe to eat. If the outside is brown then you're generally good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to address your concern of whether or not your steak is "too rare."  Steak is safely eaten in a range of raw to well done.  Safety depends on product quality and safe handling procedures.  I would say your pictures range from "looking" rare to medium rare. The only way to be more explicit is to know the exact temperature, as sometimes color is not an accurate indicator.